# Runnable not running at all inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, runnable

I'm trying to connect a SeekBar to MediaPlayer  in a fragment but the runnable isn't running at all. I put a log.i in it to see if it runs but nothing happens at all.

I declare Handler as a global variable:

```
Handler seekHandler;
SeekBar sBar;
```

And then in *onCreateView*:

```
seekHandler = new Handler();
sBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
```

Runnable:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        sBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        sBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
        Log.i("TAG", "I'm running");
        seekHandler.postDelayed(this, 25);
    }
};
```

**mp** variable is a MediaPlayer. The problem is that the Runnable doesn't exexute even once. I am using the **exact** same code in my similar application in **activity** and it's working completely fine. Is this because runnables act differently in a Fragment? Also I'm using TabLayout with ViewPager and 2 Fragments, if that affects any of this.

Comment: You're trying to request and set progress from a non-main thread. That shouldn't be possible to start with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to run it at lease once before the handler can submit it again.

From your class you should call `seekHandler.post(run)`, or `run.run();` at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the code where you execute the Runnable. By the looks of it you'll have to use
    runOnUiThread(run);

since you're accessing the Ui from inside the runnable